# Wifi extenders or ap's for large home?

Tags: wireless-networking

I've looked for answers on this, but I'm a bit confused with the answers and/or terminology.

I'm in a new, large wheelchair friendly bungalow, I had planned network points in each room but I don't have them yet, long story.

I've bought some netgear extender/ap's but I'm no network expert and I'm not sure how I should be setting them up.

So far I've connected both to the wifi router in extender mode and they're working fine, but each has a unique ssid and it's range is tied to the router.  I was hoping each extender would extend from the position the last, daisy chain I guess.

I would sooner not have multiple ssid's as I use a fair amount of mobile tech, but the range is more important.  And I'm really not bothered about increasing latency.

How should I be setting these up for best coverage?

Many thanks.

Comment: In a daisychain method you need usually a wifi controller, this is more business product because of the price, for home I would rather use a router with big antenna and a big range in the middle of the home.

Comment: When the cabling is installed I will be able to move the router.  But of course then I'll have sockets I can use.

Comment: I didn't think ENTER would send my reply.  Because I don't have sockets and can't move the router I bought the extenders.  What is the best setup for the extenders to provide coverage?  (Netgear

Comment: What is the house size? as my house is 40x30 feets, with brick, and a small soho router without external antenna cover the house and a big part outside the house

Comment: The problem is more to do with the layout than size, although it is large.  There is a central galley kitchen with rooms at the ends and sides.  Because the builder luvvies have gone mental with that paper fibre insulation everywhere wifi signals are stopped dead where there isn't a doorway or window, so I was hoping to daisy chain a couple of extenders in line of sight.   It appears I won't be able to do this easily.  I do have another router of the same kind, is there any way I can utilise this?

Comment: Range extenders will cut the bandwidth by at least half because Wi-Fi devices cannot both send and receive at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion. I suggest AP in the room where the signal cut. To make thing easy I would use the same SSID than your main router. That way each device will be able to connect anywhere.

I give that tip as your material cut the wifi signal, thus you have not to worry to have two overlapping signal with the same SSID.

I would not use a router in AP mode, as it would work, but the device behind it will be in a double NAT mode, thus it can break some application to work correctly.

Comment: However, to use these as an AP I will need a network port?  And I don't have any.

Comment: I've seen units that will send data through the standard electric sockets and I believe they act as wired ports.  Are those an option and could you recommend any?  Thanks.